# Values in Hibernate

Tags: reactjs, sql-server, hibernate

I want a row in hibernate that only takes ("yes","no"," "), how can I map it?

Something like an ENUM type in SQL but mapped in Hibernate

Comment: have you tried a boolean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ENUM in an Entity class.

Create an enum class like below:

```
public enum UserSelectionENUM {
   YES, NO;
}
```

and then Map it to your Entity class:

```
@Column(name = "user_selection")
private UserSelectionENUM userSelection;
```

By default the Enumurated type is ordinal, which means you'll have to use `int` as your datatype in your database.
However if you want to store string in your database you should explicitly define it as

```
@Column(name = "user_selection")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private UserSelectionENUM userSelection;
```